# MongoTemplate Criteria Query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm generating a complicated `Mongo` query depending on multiple parameters. One of criterion that I want to make with `Criteria` helper class is:

```
{"field1": {$exists: true, $ne: false}}
```

I tried to make it with:

```
Criteria.where("field1").is(Criteria.where("$ne").is(false).and("$exists").is(true))
```

But it generates:

```
{ "field1" : { $java : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria@23864e60 }
```

So, **how to achieve the exact query that i need?**
I can't hardcode that query string, because these type criterions are generated dynamically for field1,...fieldN and then combined with `$or`:

```
statusCriteria = statusCriteria.orOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]));
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you can’t use [**`Criteria.and()`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#and-java.lang.String-) to add multiple criteria into the same field, use [**`Criteria.andOperator()`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#andOperator-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...-) as follows:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(
    new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("field1").exists(true),
        Criteria.where("field1").ne(false)
    )
);

List<Foo> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, Foo.class);
System.out.println("query - " + query.toString());

for (Foo foo : result) {
    System.out.println("result - " + foo);
}
```

Comment: That generates following block { "$and" : [ { "field" : { "$exists" : true}} , { "field" : { "$ne" : false}}]} that is not exactly what I need, but logically it is. Wouldn't it result in perfomance issues because of doubling "field"?

Comment: @Aeteros No perfomance issues at all. From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), MongoDB provides an implicit `AND` operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit `AND` with the `$and` operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

Comment: @chridam - thank you so much. Your solution worked perfectly. Gr8 Job!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("field1").exists(true).ne(false));
```

Or, if field1 is always a boolean value when present:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("field1").is(true));
```