# $or operator with multiple expressions and multiple fields in an expression using Spring Data Reactive MonogoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-reactive

In MongoDB, I can use `$or[{key1:'value11', key2:'value12'}, {key1:'value21', key2:'value22'}, {key1:'value31', key2:'value32'}, ...]` to query several documents which matches at least one of the expressions in the `$or` operator. Then how the thing can be done using Spring Data Reactive MonogoDB?

In particular, I define a entity class as:

```
@Document
public class MyDocument
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2; 
}
```

And then, the repository interface for the entity:

```
  public interface MyDocumentRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDocument, String>
```

The question now is how to define a method in `MyDocumentRepository` to query the documents with `field1` and `field2`:

1. There seems no proper keywords to create a query method (`findAllBy(field1AndField2)In`???)
2. If using JSON-based Query Methods, I really do know how to complete the Cloze test...

   ```
   @Query("{$or:[(:fields)]}
   Flux<MyDocument> findAllBy????(Flux<???> fields)
   ```

Comment: you can use reactive mongo template instead, right? If so then we can write the query with Criteria

Comment: @CaptainLevi Thanks a lot for your kind information. But I'm not familiar with `ReactiveMongoTemplate` and also how to build a criteria of &or operator. Could you please provide some more detail info. ?

Comment: You can configure it with https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive#mongoTemplate and use Criteria with `and` and `or` operation similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33546797/6777170 , let me know if this works for you so I could write it as an answer for better visibility for people with similar problem

Comment: @CaptainLevi Yes, it really works! Furthermore, I found that the `ReactiveMongoTemplate` bean can be automatically wired without defining it in configuration class. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB has support for `ReactiveMongoTemplate`. In a repository, you can use this as a connection to MongoDB which can be used with `@Autowire`.

In `ReactiveMongoTemplate` you can create `Criteria` with `and` and `or` operation like

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(
    new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("field1").exists(true),
        Criteria.where("field1").ne(false)
    )
);
```

and this can be passed to MongoDB with the before created instance of `ReactiveMongoTemplate`

```
Flux<Foo> result = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, Foo.class);
```

Documentation for use of configuration of `ReactiveMongoTemplate` if needed can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive#mongoTemplate)